# What is the difference between the cosmological and the black hole horizons in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, event-horizon

I want to know the different thermal behaviors between cosmological and black hole horizons, such as temperature, entropy and so on.